# How to play a audio sound in a web page as a background music

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript

I want to play an audio file whenever my page gets loaded onto the client browser. And if a user presses a pause button on the web page then the sound gets paused until he leaves the sound and can resume as well. ?

Comment: Please reconsider.  Web pages that play sounds are rarely, if ever, a good idea.

Comment: It's typically considered bad web ettiquette nowadays to  automatically play a sound file on a web page unless the client knows ahead of time that they are browsing to a page with a sound/video/etc. (i.e. YouTube, etc)

Comment: Don't do it.  Really, don't do it.  Automatically playing sounds are worse than the blink tag.

Comment: I did this back in 1995 for a webpage with all manner of bad web design ideas. Don't repeat my mistakes!

Comment: actually I m developing a site for a rock band group, for that only i want to play a background sound file, which can be stopped if user wants.

Comment: Don't auto play it then.

Comment: k fine, but how to play it, didn't get solution yet

Comment: Please don't? I'm having horrible flashbacks of Geocities and the 90s.

Comment: When I go to a rock band page I don't want it to blast music out my speakers and make me scramble to turn it down. Users looking for a rock band will choose to hit Play, don't worry, but at their own timing - it's not fair to push your timing on them.

I don't care if the website is for the Queen of England and you're playing some nice classical background music automatically - "If it ain't baroque, don't fix it".

Comment: Everytime a web sit plays a sound automatically on load, god kills a kitten.

Comment: ok thx for suggestion, i will try my best to convince my client not to play sound automatically.

Comment: I wish there was a `Vote To close as: "I've got a bad Feeling About This."` option.

Comment: If you were making a bean bag website, would you choose to smack the user in the head with one as soon as they loaded the site? A water balloon website?

Comment: `<MARQUEE>sound.wav</MARQUEE>`  Seriously, though. If you want to play audio, I'd use flash.  Also, don't play it immediately upon opening and offer the ability to stop/pause/mute.

Comment: Assume this thread to be closed, I would not play any sound atleast in my site, and show my client all these comments. I m sure he will change his mood. he gave me a refrence of http://arttreeindia.com/ this site.

Comment: I don't care if it's a band site, I don't like going to sites and have them instantly start playing music. I'm usually already listening to music and if I want to listen to music, I'll click play.

Comment: Indeed take all these comments about not playing music automatically to your client and when they ask about our credibility well, ah ... um ... show them our points, er well.... I'm sure you'll figure something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until HTML 5, flash is going to be your best solution, this is mostly because it's an intrusion to have a page commandeer control of the user's speakers, and thus why people have recommended not doing this at all or making it so that the user must explicitly click something.

Here's a page with some freebie flash player options:
http://www.premiumbeat.com/flash_resources/free_flash_music_player/

Comment: Can you plz provide me a link to some example to make ur point more clearer.. Didn't get u how to embed flash for playing sound

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [easy musicplayer for flash](http://emff.sourceforge.net/) is a easy-to-set up MP3 player solution that does what you need. It provides "play" and "pause" buttons.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play.htm) some examples. But as some said before, its not the best idea to have sound. But if yo do at least have a toggle to mute, turn the volume down or disable it totally.

Answer (score 1):

I found this web site helpful for setting up a sound file from within a page. In my case, I only wanted it to play if they clicked something.  I would agree with others here who suggested that.

[This web site](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play.htm)
http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play.htm

One problem I have is when I have a number of web pages open and one of them starts making a sound, it is very difficult to find the page to get it to shut up.  It is better to have the user launch the sound.

Comment: thx i would prob do that to play music on user's wish. But how can i pause a music

Answer (score 0):

I guess achieving the same with jquery plugins won't be less exciting!

The [jquery mediaplayer](http://malsup.com/jquery/media/) does the same. Using this jquery plugin, you can play your media player files without the need of windows media player. The limitation is that this works only with the media player type of files.

Further, since mp3 files are highly used in web pages, we could use the [bssound jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bssound) to embed mp3 file in our web page.